# FactoryBot Undefined Method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have an existing Factory (order), and I am trying to make a new factory that effectively inherits from it. It looks like this:

```
factory :order_with_domain, :parent => :order do |o|
  o.order_provider 'DomainNameHere'
end
```

Upon doing that and running the specs with `order_with_domain`, I am greeted by this:

```
undefined method `order_provider=' for #<Order:0x00007fc70d9fafc0> 
Did you mean?  order_provider
```

I receive this same error if I try and place `order_provider` in the parent Factory.

Any helps is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your Order model have an order_provider attribute?

Comment: If it didn't, would it not provide a generic `undefined method` error rather than telling me to try `order_provider`?

From, the console, I can call `order.order_provider` and get what I need.

Comment: OK, so it seems you may have a getter (`order_provider`) but not a setter (`order_provider=`). Please edit your question to show the code for your Order model.

Comment: @IainK it did give you a generic `NoMethodError` just so happens `did_you_mean` found a similar method name and offered a suggestion. Just like `"S".chimp` asks me if I meant `chomp` or `chomp!`

Comment: It's almost certain you haven't defined `#order_provider=` (it's a different method than `#order_provider`).

Answer (score 7):

Try running `rails c test` then check if your column is present. If not then it's an issue with your test database and you need to run your migrations in the test environment using `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate`. If nothing happens, delete your `schema.rb` then run the migrations command again.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting the value in curly braces like so:

```rb
factory :order_with_domain, :parent => :order do |o|
  o.order_provider { 'DomainNameHere' }
end
```

Here is the reason [on thoughtbot](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/deprecating-static-attributes-in-factory_bot-4-11)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model has an `order_provider` attribute or `order_provider=` method, as @moveson commented above.

I would use [`traits`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits). Something like this:

```
factory :order do
  # ... original factory stuff

  trait :with_domain do
    order_provider 'DomainNameHere'
  end
end
```

Then to use it:

```
order_with_domain = FactoryBot.create(:order, :with_domain)
```

Comment: I agree this is a good use case for a trait, but it's not going to work if there is no method for `Order#order_provider=`.

Comment: There is no `order_provider=` method. Look at the OP's error message.

Comment: It certainly is possible, but uncommon if `order_provider` is not an attribute on model.